OHIO - What are my options to put my 4 year old daughter to Preschool?
Here is my situation: I moved to this country 3 months ago. I wasn't aware how schools work in this country. I'm still learning about the school system. My kid is turning 4 years old this month. My kid is not a native English speaker.
I called the county school system, and they said they are full. I looked at a nearby church school and they are full as well? What can I do? I feel like me being "lazy" about it has made it bad for my kid.
Could you please suggest something?

I don't know what the situation is in Ohio (hence no answer), but I know of areas where the waiting time to get into primary school is between 1 and 4 years. Don't beat yourself up if you moved only 3 months ago and started looking for (pre-)schools quite soon afterward.

Every area in the US is different, so I'm glad you specified your state, although it also varies by town/city. Here is some basic information that you may or may not already know, followed by some more specific advice.
Public School Districts
Each state is divided into school districts. Typically, a district represents a city or town. In more rural areas, some districts serve multiple towns. Each home has a single assigned public school district based on its address. So if you move, you may find yourself in a different district. (In that case, schools have rules about what happens, but those rules vary by school.)
School districts typically include one or more of each of the following school types:

Elementary School (nearly always includes children up to age 10, although some elementary schools include children up to age 12.)
Middle School (usually for children ages 11-13, although sometimes that varies. Sometimes this is known as Junior High.)
High School (usually for children ages 14+)

In many suburban school districts, there are multiple small elementary schools, which then combine into one or two middle schools and one high school. In this case, students are usually assigned to a school based on their home address and current age.
In particularly large urban districts, there may be many elementary schools and even multiple high schools, in those cases, there is often a way for students to choose which high school they most want to go to, with those high schools frequently specializing in things like sciences, arts, etc. Still, elementary schools are typically assigned by home address, since students are too young to choose.
In particularly small rural districts, there may only be one elementary school that everyone in the district attends. In some instances, the middle school and high school may even be combined into the same building.
Public Vs Private Schools
Public school districts are funded by taxes and are free for all children to attend. They receive additional support by the federal and state governments for extra services, such as support for students with disabilities, language learning services, and free or reduced meals for low income students. Public schools are measured and graded by their state, and are supposed to all be held to the same standards/teach a very similar curriculum. However, their quality can vary widely, partly because the funding they receive depends on their local property taxes. In wealthy areas, public schools tend to be well funded and (often) are very high quality. In lower income areas, they sometimes struggle to receive enough funding and may not have enough resources to effectively teach their students.
Private schools are not funded by the government, and are instead typically funded by the families that send their children there in the form of tuition. Some schools are also affiliated with religious organizations and may be partially funded as a charity through that affiliation. Private schools vary more widely than public schools do, and each one works differently. If you have more questions about this, those would be good to ask separately, since this answer will already be so long.
Charter Schools/Magnet Schools are additional types of public schools that receive funding and resource allocation in slightly different ways. They are also free for students to attend, but have a unique set of strengths and challenges. Please ask additional questions if you are confused about something you are seeing related to these terms.
Grade Levels
In the US, children are assigned a grade level based on their age and ability level. The standard levels are 1st grade (typically for students around 6 years old) to 12th grade (typically for students turning 18 years old).
Before 1st grade comes Kindergarten, which is often abbreviated as K, where students are typically about 5 years old. Kindergarten is the first year of mandatory schooling in the US, which means that school districts are only required to provide schooling for students ages 5 and up.
Some schools have options before Kindergarten, as follows:

Pre-Kindergarten (PK) - usually age 4
Pre-School (PS) - Usually age 3
Daycare/Nursery - Usually ages 12-36 months, but sometimes younger.

These options might be offered in a half-day format (usually about 3 hours) or in a full-day format (usually about 6 hours). They often cost money and there are often long waitlists. There are some non-profit organizations that provide free or very low-cost childcare to students in this age range, but they vary by geographic region.
Suggestions
I would recommend reaching back out to your school district and asking the following:

Next year, when your child will be 5, they should be able to enroll in Kindergarten. Ask the school to tell you more about the process for Kindergarten enrollment so that you know what to expect. Is there an open house you can attend before the school year starts so that you can see the school and meet the teachers? When do you need to file the paperwork? What documentation do they need from you?
Let the school know that your child does not currently speak English and that you just moved to the US. Ask them about their ESL services for young students, and ask to be put in touch with someone from that program. This person may be able to connect you with additional resources in the meantime so that your child can begin learning more English now.
Explain that you just moved to the US and aren't sure how to navigate the system. Ask if they can give you advice on finding a PK program for your child for this year.

Next, I would recommend connecting with any non-profits in the area that work with immigrants or refugees (even if you are not a refugee yourself). They will be able to give you the best advice local to your region and help answer lots of questions about services available for your family. They also might know of PK programs that are still accepting students now.
Finally, if you are struggling to find local resources, I recommend going to your local public library and speaking with the children's librarian. Libraries are community centers that can help connect you with resources, learn about your new community, and navigate all the confusing paperwork.
Best of luck, and welcome!
